# views_embed_view('FeaturedSalesProperties','default')

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am new in drupal. and I have this piece of code:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('FeaturedSalesProperties','default');?>
```

in page-node-3167.tpl.php

it prints on site 3 random featured ads... and I do not understand what SELECT in DB is executed...

I found record in views_view with name FeaturedSalesProperties and base_table node but still do not know how this 3 ads are chosen...

Also it looks like the drupal site is modified because if i wanna access site/admin there is no drupal administration...

Can anybody explain me how can I modify this view so it will print not 3 random featured ads but all of them?

Thanks

Comment: This code means you are rendering data from a View named FeaturedSalesProperties, showing the default view. You need to look at what that view is doing to get the ads. Probably you will need to remove a where clause filter

Comment: ok and can you point me to some tutorial or something, or at least where I can find that filter? because I found the template which render it, but it is just foreach cycle... All what I found wass just tutorial how to do some stuff in drupal administration... not without it... also II looked into code of function but it is a little complicated because you need to look into lot of stuff if you do not know where to look exactly... thx

Comment: When working with views you really don't want to go into the code if you can help it. Especially for something like this, go into the edit view screen through the drupal admin interface, and edit the view. You will see a section named filters, and should be able to make your change there.

Comment: Ok, but page has own admin template, so I do not have any options for structure and this stuff, where can I turn default admin on? or how can I access it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a way how to edit it without drupal administer... all values are in DB...

at first find your view in `view_view` table
second find in view_display record with the same vid as your view...
look into field display_options and that it is...

It is quite complicated to find which value to change but it is possible :D also it is helpful if you can create some view in other drupal system and watch what has been changed if you turn this option or this...